# Calculate $\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{n}{n^2 + 1} + \frac{n}{n^2 + 2} + \cdots + \frac{n}{n^2 + n}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

> Calculate $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \bigg(\frac{n}{n^2 + 1} + \frac{n}{n^2 + 2} + \cdots + \frac{n}{n^2 + n}\bigg)$$

Hello!

The answer given to this problem is $1$, but I am getting to $0$:

Consider $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{n^2 + k} \stackrel{\text{L'Hopital}}{=} \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{2n} = 0.$$

Now, since in the original expression, all the individual limits exist and are defined, the answer is $0 + 0 + \cdots + 0 = 0$, which is wrong answer.

I can guess where I go wrong: the number of terms is something that depends on $n$, but when doing L'Hopital, I am treating is as constant.

But, I am still not clear about this. How exactly is this method wrong?

*Please note that my question is not about how to solve this question, but about why a particular method is wrong. I already know it has got answers in a different post.*

Comment: Helpful will be to look at integral.

Comment: The number of terms becomes arbitrarily large, so the summing-$0$s argument doesn't work.

Comment: The issue is that even though the terms become small, the _number of terms_ you're summing becomes large. Indeed, the terms decay like $\frac{1}{n}$ but the number of terms grows like $n$. So (informally) it's reasonable to expect these two cancel out to get a constant limit.

Comment: @J.G. Why not? $0$ is $0$ and no matter how many times I sum it, it would be $0$, wouldn't it?

Comment: Notice that $$\frac{n}{n^2+k}=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{k}{n(n^2+k)}=\frac{1}{n}-O\left(\frac{k}{n^3}\right)$$ so by summing these quantities over $k\in[1,n]$ we get $1-O(1/n)$.

Comment: But you're not summing $n$ copies of $0$; you're summing $n\to\infty$ terms that have individual $\to0$ but positive behaviours as $n\to\infty$. Once we evaluate the limit correctly as per e.g. @MathFail's answer, this problem constitutes a counterexample of the conjecture that your strategy works. If you try rigorously proving it works in general, you won't be able to do it.

Comment: By the way, although this question has been marked as a duplicate, the other question solves a different problem, but exploiting the same strategy, namely using $\frac{1}{n+1}\le\frac{n}{n^2+k}\le\frac1n$ together with the squeeze theorem.

Comment: @J.G. Yes, I have edited and voted to reopen the question. Regarding my question: here's my doubt: $$\lim_{x \to c} (f(x) + g(x)) = \lim_{x \to c} f(x) + \lim_{x \to c} g(x)$$ if **both the limits exist and are defined**. When adding the limits (**all which exist and have a defined value of $0$**), no matter infinity times, I am still adding $0$, which will remain $0$. I am just following the addition law for limits. Why is it wrong then?

Comment: @MangoPizza Again, the sum is of functions of $n$ which have limit $0$, which is an important subtlety. You can prove by induction on $k$ that if $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_i(n)$ exists for $1\le i\le k$ their sum is $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^ka_i(n)$, but that has an $n$-independent number of terms. The law you quote doesn't generalize beyond that as you desire. However, I've voted to reopen, which it seems did the trick.

Comment: @J.G. Oh, I see. Basically the law I mention doesn't hold for infinite terms (only for finite number times), does it?

Comment: Got it in one. That's the trouble with an infinite sum: proofs by induction about what happens with $k$ terms don't tell you much.

Comment: @J.G. Thank you very much. Would you mind posting it as answer, so that I can close this post and future viewers can directly view the answer?

Comment: OP  is summing very small numbers (zeros) infinite times so the limit is indeterminate $0\times \infty$ warning that a special method is required e.g. sqeez law used in one of the answers below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing comments to an answer as the OP requested:

The claim

> If $A_i:=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_i(n)$ exist for $1\le i\le k$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^ka_i(n)=\sum_{i=1}^kA_i$

is famous in the case $k=2$, from which we can prove it for all finite integers $k\ge0$ by induction on $k$. This does not, however, prove an infinite-$k$ or $n$-dependent $k$ case. Since @MathFail's answer shows the true limit is $1$, this problem provides a counterexample to any such conjecture.

Answer (score 1):

For each term, $\frac{n}{n^2+k}$ it goes to arbitrarily small, say $\frac{n}{n^2+k}\to \epsilon$. But you have infinitely many terms sum together, so what is the sum of infinitely many $\epsilon$? It is undetermined!

Note that:

$$\frac{n}{n^2+n}\le\frac{n}{n^2+k}\le\frac{n}{n^2+1}$$

So we have:

$$\frac{n^2}{n^2+n}=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{n}{n^2+n}\le\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{n}{n^2+k}\le\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{n}{n^2+1}=\frac{n^2}{n^2+1}$$

Further:

$$1=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^2}{n^2+n}\le\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{n}{n^2+k}\le\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^2}{n^2+1}=1$$

From Squeeze theorem, we know the limit is $1$